# Как заставить срабатывать событие click на сенсорных устройствах?

Tags: javascript

Возникла проблема не работает событие клика на сенсорных устройствах iPad, iPhone и прочие. Как поправить эту беду.

Пример из файла script.js:

```
$('body').on('click', '.qr-code-generate', function(){ 
// что-то делаем. 
});
```

И таких много в коде. И в том числе это должно работать на подгружаемых элементах, на PC работает нормально, а вот на сенсорах вообще не хочет...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плагин Jtap

```
<script src="jquery.tap.min.js"></script>

$('selector').tap(handler); - устанавливаем обработчик там где надо вместо события click
```

Comment: а как быть с функцией исполняемой при событии клик, выносить в отдельную именованную функцию? или можно так $('selector').tap(function(){ ...});

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev можно так